# GUI for creating Azure Database Tables

Tags: user-interface, azure, azure-sql-database

Before moving to Azure I used to create and modify data tables for my Database within Visual Studio 2010 directly from the Server Explorer (`Add New Table` / `Open Table Definition`).

Unfortunately it does not seem possible any longer to do this for an SQL Azure Database, "feature not supported". Does anybody know of a GUI based tool for creating and modifying data table schemas? I could obviously script these changes but it's so much quicker with a GUI.

Does Visual Studio 2012 support this?

Comment: Just a quick note to say that as of today (11/04/13) neither VS2012 with SSDT nor SSMS support graphical creation of Azure tables.  You can script them, but there is not feature parity with On-Premise SQL Server.  Also note that VS2012 with SSDT has graphical table editing, but SSMS does not.  I am scratching my head wondering why what you're asking for wasn't included in all three toolsets.

Comment: Very odd! I have the same frustration with the lack of intellisense for Azure Database Scripting, it makes working with Azure DBs so much slower. Although regarding GUI editing for SSDT + VS2012 it seems to be present (based on @Nico's post)? Unless MS have withdrawn this in a recent update?

Comment: Nico is correct that you can EDIT tables in VS2012, but I promise that you can't CREATE tables without scripting.  My VS2012 is the Professional Edition and is fully updated.  I'm now developing my db locally and then using scripts to move it up to Azure en masse, but looking forward this will not work too well once I have data in my tables in Azure and want to keep it intact.

Comment: I have just successfully created and synced an Azure table using the GUI in Entity Framework in VS2012.  It's not as easy as SSMS, but it is a pretty good modeling tool all in all.

Comment: That's interesting. We currently use ADO.NET, is migrating to Entity Framework a big job? Does EF provide a more effective interface to SQL Azure Database?

Comment: There is no easy answer to that first question - I think you should investigate EF and see what you think based on the size of your implementation.  Pluralsight.com has some excellent courses on EF, that's what I"m using to come up to speed really quickly.  As for the second question, it's not a simple management tool and if that's all you need then no it is not more effective.  It is more effective from my perspective, but I really hope that Microsoft updates SSDT and/or SSMS soon to bring full feature parity with Azure SQL.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, the Server Explorer of Visual Studio 2012 supports connections to SQL Azure Databse servers. But you can also use the free [SQL Server Express Management Studio 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22985) (or newer) to connect to SQL Azure or even use the designer in the SQL Server Management Portal.

**Edit:**

I see you would like to have a designer UI. There's no such feature in SSMS as far as I know but Visual Studio 2012 does support this feature. If you don't want to switch to VS2012 you still can user the UI from the SQL Azure Management portal.

- Visual Studio 2012 [image: Database Designer for SQL Azure from VS2012]
- SQL Azure Management Portal [image]

Comment: Connecting to the database is fine, I already have SSMS 2012 Express installed on my dev machine but there's no GUI for creating tables in SSMS or VS2010. Are you saying in VS2012 there is a GUI for creating/modifying tables that works with Azure Databases?

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, looks like it's time to upgrade to VS2012.

Comment: I saw somewhere a nice, graphical representation of the tables in the DB. It had lines between the boxes corresponding to the tables' foreign keys and such. Very informative **but** I don't know if it was a real tool or just a presentation that someone drew manually. Have you seen it? What's it called?

Comment: Such a representation is usually shown when you are using an O/R-Mapper such as LinqToSQL or EntityFramework. If you are using Visual Studio go and add a new EntityFramework model to your solution and generate the model from an existing database. You can also drag and drop classes (tables) and connections on the design surface and create a database from that. Such diagrams are referred to as Entity-Models or Entity-Relationship-Models. Hope that helps.

Comment: There's a feature called "Database Diagrams" that is present in some SKUs of SQL Server (SQL Azure does not support them) - here's a link to a walkthrough: http://sqlmag.com/database-development/jump-start-creating-database-diagrams

Comment: Hi, sorry for resurrecting old topic, but is it possible to edit Insert and Update scripts via SQL Azure Management Portal ?

Answer (score 4):

How about the SSDT (SQL Server Data Tool) which shipped along with SQL Server 2012 and integrated with VS2012. It support GUI for SQL Server as well as SQL Azure.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx

http://blogs.shaunxu.me/archive/2012/04/28/ssdt-ndash-makes-sql-azure-development-easy.aspx

Comment: Shaun, that sounds like it may work! I'm looking for an excuse to upgrade to VS2012 so this may be it.

Comment: Not pretty sure but as far as I know, SSDT works with VS2010.